# Laravel How to update multiple records using request all

Tags: laravel

How to update all records using `request->all()`, I have many columns to update.
here is my code for create method which I am using to insert multiple new records which is working fine.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $teacher = new Teacher;
    $teacher::create($request->all());
    $teacher->save();
    return back()->with('message','Teacher Added Successfully!');
}
```

here is what I tried but it's not working,

```
public function update(Request $request, Teacher $teacher)
{
    $teachers=$request->all();
    $teacher->save();
    return back()->with('message','Record Successfully Updated!');
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of this:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Teacher $teacher)
{
    $teachers = $request->all();
    $teacher->save();
    return back()->with('message', 'Record Successfully Updated!');
}
```

You have to **try this**:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Teacher $teacher)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $teacher->fill($input)->save();
    return back()->with('message', 'Record Successfully Updated!');
}
```

Assuming that you have to create `fillable` property in your `Teacher` model.

I hope it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Fill method needs key/value array. Will update work in this case?

Comment: Yeah, it work in this case because `$request->all()` get also key/value array.

Comment: Why can the $teacher object be empty? I'm correctly passing the id in the url and I'm sure it exists in the database

Answer (score 3):

```
public function update(Request $request, Teacher $teacher)
{
    /*
     * For the love of god, validate your data!!!
     */
    $attributes = $this->validate($request, $rules);
    $teacher->update($attributes);

    return ...
}
```